# Virtual Box and ExpressVPN

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vpn, virtual-machine, operating-systems

I have been trying to solve this issue for 3 weeks now, is there a way I can use ExpressVPN network only to access a Virtual Machine?

And if that connection failed for some reason it will not switch to my home network?

Comment: I think you mean like "use ExpressVPN for only traffics from a VM (but not those from the VM host)"? It's probably feasible if the VM host is Linux, but it's gonna be complexed since it would require policy routing or even netns. The general idea is to use host-only networking (yes despite its name), which allows you customize IP forwarding and NAT, in which case you can then run both the VPN and VBox in a netns or establish policy routing between them. (You probably need to use static IP configuration inside the VM, or set up an external DHCP server for it.)

Comment: It's probably easier to just run ExpressVPN inside the VM and implement some kind of kill-switch inside. Is there a reason that is not an option for you?

Comment: Hello Tom, i am already running the expressvpn inside the VM, but sometimes the kill switch does not work, I do not want my main network to connect to the VM if the vpn went down

Comment: @king you should add this information to your question.  Also what OS and VPN protocol you are using and how DNS is set up if you know.